# SQL Server 2012: Multiple select count(column1) in a single query from different table causing errors

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to fetch counts from different tables in SQL Server 2012.

My query looks like:

```
SELECT  
    (
        (SELECT COUNT(dbo.Table1.column1) FROM dbo.Table1) AS A,
        (SELECT COUNT(dbo.Table2.column1) FROM ddbo.Table2) AS B,
        (SELECT COUNT(dbo.Table3.column1) FROM dbo.Table3) AS C
    )
```

I get these errors:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Please help me out of this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to:

```
SELECT  
       (Select count(dbo.Table1.column1) from dbo.Table1) AS A,
       (Select count(dbo.Table2.column1) from dbo.Table2) AS B,
       (Select count(dbo.Table3.column1) from dbo.Table3) AS C
```

Comment: also `from ddbo.Table2` should probably be `from dbo.Table2`

Comment: Thanks @Giorgi Nakeuri for correction and now its woking :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [common table expression](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
WITH A(c) as (SELECT count(1) c FROM table1),
B(c) AS (SELECT count(1) c FROM table1)
SELECT A.c, B.c FROM A, B
```